# Adding 300 IP ranges to list of allowed IP addresses on a profile

Tags: metadata-api, profile

My real problem is that I need to add almost 300 IP ranges to the list of allowed IP addresses of a profile (thanks, Microsoft).

It seems there is still no simple solution for this. [On this site](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/53933/bulk-upload-ip-ranges-into-profile) I found out that the way to go is to use something called the Metadata API Toolkit. In Classic it could be found via Setup > Develop > Tools, but if I switch nowadays to Classic and look over there, I cannot find it. There is a link to a page called Lightning Platform Tools and Toolkits, but the list on that page does not contain a Metadata API Toolkit.

So it no longer exists or it is no longer supported?

Where can I find it?

If it is no longer available, what other way is there to bulk upload IP ranges to the allowed list of a profile?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Profile Login IP Ranges via API](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/15701/profile-login-ip-ranges-via-api)

Comment: You can also try https://github.com/keirbowden/bbsfdx - found via Google, caveat emptor.

Comment: @identigral No, technically it does not answer my question, because that question+answers do not point me to the Metadata Toolkit API. However, I hope the answers there can help me. Unfortunately the code samples are in Java, not Apex, so that is another hurdle to overcome.

Comment: For Apex, try https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi

Comment: @identigral Yes, I had found that one as well. I guess I'll have to make a new sandbox, download this thing and see what it looks like. Thanks for the pointers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Metadata API Toolkit is long obsolete, that post is 7 years old. Nowadays you should use [sfdx](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/sfdxcli)

Once you installed it you can connect it to your org using the `sfdx auth:web:login` command (run `sfdx help auth:web:login` for more info)

Then you can retreive the profile using `sfdx force:source:retrieve -m Profile:MyProfileName` add the ranges to the retreived file and deploy it again using `sfdx force:source:deploy` (the help command also works for retreive and deploy)

Edit: the link that identigral shared in their comment is a plugin for sfdx that can make it a bit easier, but you don't need the plugin to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks! I already had sfdx on my system. Your answer is the closest to the original Metadata API Toolkit approach.

Answer (score 1):

As @identigral stated, you are able to accomplish your task with [MetadataService](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi/blob/master/apex-mdapi/src/classes/MetadataService.cls).

All you need to do is to know exactly what fullName does Profile have on Metadata level. [This question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/113370/how-to-match-profile-name-to-ant-metadata-profile-name-and-vice-versa) may help you. For eample, `Admin` states for `System Administrator`.

Also you need to set up lists of ranges from your document, for a code sample I have created range `0.0.0.0 - 255.255.255.255`. This will add new IP ranges to existing ones in Profile.

```
List<String> startRange = new List<String>{
        '0.0.0.0', '2.2.2.2'
};
List<String> endRange = new List<String>{
        '1.1.1.1', '3.3.3.3'
};

MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
service.SessionHeader.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();
service.CallOptions = new MetadataService.CallOptions_element();
service.timeout_x = 120000;

List<MetadataService.Profile> profiles = (List<MetadataService.Profile>) service.readMetadata('Profile', new List<String>{'Admin'}).getRecords(); //read Profile to get existing IP ranges

MetadataService.Profile profile = new MetadataService.Profile();
profile.fullName = 'Admin';
if (profiles[0].loginIpRanges != null) {
    profile.loginIpRanges = profiles[0].loginIpRanges; //set existing IP ranges
} else {
    profile.loginIpRanges = new List<MetadataService.ProfileLoginIpRange>(); //if no IP ranges existed, add empty list
}

for (Integer i = 0; i < startRange.size(); i++) {
    MetadataService.ProfileLoginIpRange ipRange = new MetadataService.ProfileLoginIpRange();
    ipRange.startAddress = startRange[i];
    ipRange.endAddress = endRange[i];
    profile.loginIpRanges.add(ipRange); //add new IP ranges
}

List<MetadataService.SaveResult> saveResults = service.updateMetadata(new List<MetadataService.Profile>{profile});
```

Comment: I have two observations on this. First, this will not compile as MetadataService.MetadataPort does not exist in standard Apex. I think you have installed a library first that contains this. Second, are you sure this will *add* IP ranges? It does not do a retrieve first, so I think it will replace the existing IP ranges.

Comment: @SanderdeJong I have added link to https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi/blob/master/apex-mdapi/src/classes/MetadataService.cls file, where you can get MetadataService with all related classes in it. I have also tested it, it will update login ranges with the ones you'll add (replace in another words). However, you can retrieve Profile metadata first with readMetadata, if you already have some ranges and add new ones to existing `loginIpRanges` list.

Comment: @SanderdeJong I have updated the code to match your use case: retrieve existing IP ranges and add new ones.

Comment: I appreciate your efforts, thanks very much. I choose the approach with SFDX, because for me manipulating an XML is easier and cleaner than doing it via code. Also, I do not like to install a third-party library, which I would be required to review extensively. Just installing it can potentially cause trouble, Log4j taught us that much at least.

Comment: Yep, you are right, of course, but that is not actually a third-party library, this is code generated from .wsdl file, which can be generated directly from SF: Setup -> API -> Metadata API. Just with some minor improvements for readMetadata_element and tests added. 
But I believe, for your use case XML option is much more suitable.