# Allow-list IP on salesforce environment automation / Programatically

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, cicd

I have scenario, Need to allow-list IP address in Salesforce from a CI pipeline (Azure DevOps pipeline), IP address is azure DevOps Microsoft hosted agent.

Is there a way to achieve this using SFDX cli or Programmatic means?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/365739/adding-300-ip-ranges-to-list-of-allowed-ip-addresses-on-a-profile/365751#365751)

Part of it can be done with sfdx cli (retrieving and deploying the profile metadata) but you will have to script something to add the IP addresses to the metadata file yourself.

Comment: I wanted to add the IP to setup --> Network Access.

Comment: You can retrieve those with sfdx as well, they should be in force-app/main/default/settings/Security.settings-meta.xml